# If my coefficents are all unknown how do I solve for eiganvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

If my coefficents are all unknown and are replaced instead wiht a,b,c how do I know my general solution if I don't know if the eigenvalues are real, complex, or repeating?

$(A- \lambda)x=0$

Comment: You'd rather specify the problem.

Comment: As in if eigenvalues are real, the equation is blah blah blah, if the are repeating, blah blah blah?

Comment: As in, what is the context of this. Coefficients of what are unknown (OK, I can guess that you're talking about some matrix). What's the size of the matrix? $n\times n$? $2\times 2$? General solution to what? I see you've tagged this differential equations, so presumably the matrix comes from some differential equation you want to solve. What's the equation? How did you get the matrix? You need to give more information, because as it stands it's very unclear what you're trying to do and how one should answer.